# Concatenate two column values coming from a SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, last_name, employeeID FROM ecc_employee WHERE first_name != '' ");

$resources = array();

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){            
    $name = ($row['first_name']);
    $id =  $row['employeeID'];

    $resources[] = array(
    'name' =>  "$name",
    'id' => "$id"
    );
```

I need the $name to have both the first name and last name.  How would I do this?

How would I declare the $name =

Comment: SELECT CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) as name, employeeID FROM ecc_employee WHERE ...

Comment: $name[first_name] = lastname;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function:

```
SELECT ...
       CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) AS name
       ...
```

In your code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) AS name, employeeID FROM ecc_employee WHERE first_name != '' ");
```

And call it with:

```
$row['name']
```

You can also name `employeeID` as `id` to skip reassign array keys in while loop:

```
$result    = mysql_query("SELECT CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) AS name, employeeID AS id FROM ecc_employee WHERE first_name != '' ");
$resources = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){            
    $resources[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$name = $row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name'];
```

Alternatively you can use the mysql CONCAT function, as suggested.
Further info here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Answer (score 0):

Using [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

```
// of course connect goes first
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS name, employeeID AS id 
        FROM ecc_employee WHERE first_name != ''";
$stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute();
$resources = $stm->fetchAll();
```